# Angular Testing - Karma or Protractor?

Tags: angularjs

I am highly confused to test my angular application by selecting the frame work of either Karma or Protractor - which one do I need to use?

If Karma is for unit tests and Protractor for external testing, how do I integrate both in a single application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, Karma is for unit testing, whereas Protractor is for end-to-end testing.  Both of these types are described in documentation:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing
- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing

Comment: can we run both by parallel?

Comment: you mean "can we use both in the same project"? yes, and we should :)

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share a tutorial for that?